# Proxy is not working in chromeOptions in webDriver with selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using proxy in chrome driver but is it not working it is showing my local network only instead of proxy network.

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
proxy.setHttpProxy("proxyhost:proxyport");
proxy.setSocksUsername("ProxyUsername");
proxy.setSocksPassword("ProxyPassword";
chromeOptions.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setAutodetect(false);
proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
proxy.setHttpProxy("proxyhost:proxyport");
proxy.setSocksUsername("ProxyUsername");
proxy.setSocksPassword("ProxyPassword";
chromeOptions.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Another way of doing same, Please try this

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--proxy-server=http://user:password@proxy.com:8080"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```